# Как сделать процесс восстановления файла Exchange Server 2007?

Tags: outlook, exchange

Сегодня я попытался открыть баз данных Exchange Server 2007 и увидел ошибку:

> -501 0xFFFFFE0B JET_errLogFileCorrupt пытался войти но файл поврежден

Что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 2):

Поднять базу из резервной копии. Наиболее рабочий вариант.

Если нет бэкапа, копируешь файлы БД и логов в другой каталог (во избежание дальнейших потерь информации) и натравливаешь на них `eseutil /p`, `eseutil /d` и проверяешь `isinteg -fix -test alltests`. После чего пытаешься открыть восстановленную копию сервером.

[Источник](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2004/06/18/159413.aspx)